# Can you serialize one property of a collection's contained objects to JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization

How does one serialize only one property of an object when serializing a collection of that type of object to JSON?

Given a collection of objects like:

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
}
```

I want to serialize just the ID from each instance.

```
        List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
        people.Add(new Person() { ID = 1, Name = "John" });
        people.Add(new Person() { ID = 2, Name = "Paul" });
        people.Add(new Person() { ID = 3, Name = "George" });
        people.Add(new Person() { ID = 4, Name = "Ringo" });

        string beatlesJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(people);
```

As shown, it of course serializes it all like:

```
[
  {"ID":1,"Name":"John"},
  {"ID":2,"Name":"Paul"},
  {"ID":3,"Name":"George"},
  {"ID":4,"Name":"Ringo"}
]
```

I want to only serialize the IDs like:

```
[
  {"ID":1},
  {"ID":2},
  {"ID":3},
  {"ID":4}
]
```

Is there a way to do this?

I tried just building a List of the IDs, but that just serialized to an array of ints, [1,2,3,4].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.Select(x => new {ID = x.ID})`

```
 string beatlesJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(people.Select(x => new {ID = x.ID}));
```

[Try out online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WY3ANu)

Output:

```
[
   {"ID":1},
   {"ID":2},
   {"ID":3},
   {"ID":4}
]
```

Comment: Perfect.  Wasn't thinking of LINQ.